# LyX Bibliography chronological order

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, bibliographystyle

I am facing the following issue:
writing my thesis in LyX, the cited bibliography (contained in a .bib file) starts from number [2](https://pastebin.com/3EPMkN1A) and not from [1](https://pastebin.com/bTTa4FRV). The bibbliography does not appear in chronological order in the document (just for the first and second citations). The style option in LyX is "unsrt", while the format style is "Essential (BibTeX)".
Can you help me, please?

Thank you.

EDIT:
I add the link to a minimal example, but, oddly, with the option "unsrt" everything seems fine with this minimal example. https://pastebin.com/bTTa4FRV
The .bib file is here https://pastebin.com/3EPMkN1A

Comment: The style name "unsrt", mean unsorted alphabetically, i.e., the references are listed in the order that are cited, whatever the author name or the year. If this is not what you want, obviously you should choose another style.

Comment: Of course, yes. I  want them in the same order as cited, but, oddly, for the first two citations, I don't get this. The first citation starts at [2], even though it is the first work I cited.

Comment: Construct a minimal example (a very small text with three fake references or so) where this odd order happens, export t o latex and post the resulting latex code (and the .bib file with the three fake references too), so we can reproduce the problem and see what are you doing really.

Comment: I have exported a minimal example from LyX to Latex, but, as stated above, everything is fine. In my thesis, first citations refer to the ones in the .bib file I have reported, but, I get citations starting from [2] instead of [1]. Basically, they seem "swapped".